# Webpack: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'head.ejs'

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

**I have the following `webpack.config.js` file:**

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader?modules', ],
          publicPath: '/dist'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.ejs$/,
        use: 'ejs-compiled-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css'
    }),

    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      hash: true,
      template: 'ejs-render-loader!./views/index.ejs'
    }),


  ]
};
```

**When trying to load an ejs file that contains `<% somefile %>` the file cannot be found.. this is the error I receive:**

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  26.2 kB       0
    chunk    {0} index.html 554 bytes [entry]
     [./node_modules/ejs-render-loader/index.js!./views/index.ejs] ./~/ejs-render-loader!./views/index.ejs 554 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

    ERROR in ./~/ejs-render-loader!./views/index.ejs
    Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'head.ejs'
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
        at fs.readFileSync (fs.js:491:33)
        at Object.exports.parse (/var/www/rio-olympics-3/monitor/node_modules/ejs-compiled-loader/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:168:19)
        at Object.exports.compile (/var/www/rio-olympics-3/monitor/node_modules/ejs-compiled-loader/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:245:15)
        at Object.module.exports (/var/www/rio-olympics-3/monitor/node_modules/ejs-compiled-loader/index.js:7:22)
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

**I have tried many file path formats, and none of them worked, here is my ejs file with my head.ejs in the same folder:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <% include head %>

    <body>
        <div id="navbar-app"></div>
        <p> Welcome, more coming soon! </p>
    </body>


   <!-- insert component scripts below here -->
   <script src="dist/js/NavBarMain.js"></script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different loaders configured for the `index.ejs`, which results in a clash.

A general rule for all `.ejs`:

```
{
  test: /\.ejs$/,
  use: 'ejs-compiled-loader'
}
```

An inline rule for the template in `html-webpack-plugin`:

```
template: 'ejs-render-loader!./views/index.ejs'
```

If you only want to use the inline loader you can add a leading `!`, so webpack won't apply other loaders:

```
template: '!ejs-render-loader!./views/index.ejs'
```

---

The above fixes your problem, but it is a little questionable why you have two different `ejs` loaders. To be honest I'm not fully aware of the differences in the loaders since both point to the same [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bazilio91/ejs-compiled-loader), although it seems to me like `ejs-render-loader` is just an earlier version. They actually handle the includes differently, that's why you get the error.

From the example in [Usage of `ejs-compiled-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-compiled-loader#usage):

```
// Child Templates 
// path is relative to where webpack is being run 
<%- include templates/child -%>
```

That means if you want to use the `ejs-compiled-loader` for all `.ejs` you need to change the include to:

```
<% include views/head %>
```

And you can get rid of the inline loader in the `html-webpack-plugin`:

```
template: './views/index.ejs'
```

It's up to you whether you want to change this, I would just try to avoid loader conflicts and I don't think `ejs-render-loader` will be updated anymore.

In fact there is a `v2.2.0` of `ejs-compiled-loader` which went back to the other include behaviour, relative to the current file, which is definitively more intuitive. You can install it with:

```
npm install --save-dev ejs-compiled-loader@2.2.0
```

Comment: I can't find documentation for dynamic include for ejs-compiled-loader. Can you please provide an example? Also seems like the webpack doesnt watch changes on templates anymore. Do you know how get auto-watch working (webpack version 2 and ejs-compiled-loader version 2)